# How do define a timeoutId in more than one scope

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have made a classic Snake arcade game using the javascript canvas, and I am trying to build in functionality to decrement the interval on which the game animation runs. If you aren't familiar with Snake, a snake moves around the screen and attempts to eat apples that appear randomly, while trying not to run into itself or the wall. Each time the snake eats an apple, it gets longer in size and the game becomes harder. I am trying to increase the difficulty of the game by speeding up the game play each time the snake eats an apple. I have achieved that in the code snippet below:

```
//Animate the game
function gameLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
  var timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
    gameLoop();
  }, interval);
};
gameLoop(); //call the game loop
```

The problem with this is that I have a `gameOver()` function that accesses the `timeoutId` for the `setTimeout` function that runs the game, but the `timeoutId` variable is not defined at the `gameOver()` function. To make things more confusing, the `gameOver` function still works when it is supposed to, but it produces an error in the console that says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: timeoutID is not defined
    at gameOver (snake.html:68)
    at Snake.move (snake.html:157)
    at gameLoop (snake.html:253)
    at snake.html:258
```

and the `gameOver()` function does not run as it is intended. It should display "Game Over" and display the player's last score, and simply show the snake not making. Instead, when the `gameOver()` function is called, it erases the screen. Here is the `gameOver()` function:

```
function gameOver() {
  ctx.font = "60px monospace";
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText("Game Over", width/2, height/2);
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
};
```

I am wondering if there is a way that I can stop the `gameLoop()` function when a game over takes place without getting an error message and without erasing the screen. I have tried this several different ways to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `timeoutID` *outside* of `gameLoop` so that it's visible elsewhere, such as to the `gameOver` function:

```
var timeoutID;
function gameLoop() {
  // ...
  timeoutID = setTimeout( ...
  // ...
}
// ...
function gameOver() {
  // referencing timeoutID here will now be possible
```

But rather than saving the timeoutID, in this situation, you might find it a bit easier to simply have an outer *boolean* that indicates whether the `gameLoop` should run or not:

```
var gameIsOver = false;
function gameLoop() {
  if (gameIsOver) return;
  // ...
}
// ...
function gameOver() {
  gameIsOver = true;
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried defining `timeoutID` in the global scope but for some reason it didn't work before. Perhaps I mucked something up, because it worked this time. Much appreciated.